# Calculation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u|\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\ du$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to show that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u|\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\mathop{du}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\sigma(x)$$

I think it has to be shown through polar coordinates and then $u$ susbstituion, but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma(x)$?

Comment: It is the standard deviation.

Comment: So do you mean $\sigma_x$ or simply $\sigma$?

Comment: The paper I'm reading has it as $\sigma(x)$

Comment: The exact definition is $\sigma(x)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{ij}x_i x_j}$, where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the square $n\times n$ covariance matrix

Comment: I have a solution that is not quite what you are looking for, just give me a moment.

Comment: Sure, anything helps.

Comment: Are you sure you the final part is not a typo? Meaning, the correct answer has  $\sqrt{2/x}$? If that's true, then my shortcut won't work. I don't want to do real math on this.

Comment: That's a typo. That $x$ should be $\pi$

Comment: I've corrected it now

Comment: great! One moment.

Answer (score 2):

Exploit the evenness of the integrand to write

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{0}^{\infty}u\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\ du$$

Then let $ z= \frac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}$ so $\sigma{^2}(x)\ dz = u\ du$. Note that $\sigma$ has no functional dependence on $u$ and can be brought in front of the integral.

$$\begin{align*}
=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z}\sigma{^2}(x) dz \\ \\
=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma(x)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z}\ dz\\ \\
=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma(x)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that you are doing integration of an even function and $\sigma(x)$ is nothing but a constant.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}u\exp\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}}\right)\ du
= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sigma}{2}\exp\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}}\right)\ d\left(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\\
=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sigma}{2}
\int_0^\infty\exp(-v)\ dv
$$
with $\sigma:=\sigma(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u|\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\mathop{du}
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}u\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\mathop{du}-
\int_{-\infty}^{0}u\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\mathop{du}\right)=\\
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}\int_{0}^{\infty}u\operatorname{exp}\left(-\dfrac{u^2}{2\sigma{^2}(x)}\right)\mathop{du}=\\
\dfrac{2\sigma (x)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(x)}
 \left(-e^{-\frac{u^2}{2 \sigma (x)^2}}\right)\Bigg|_0^\infty
=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\sigma(x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

I will let $\sigma(x)$ be $\sigma$. Using symmetry,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|u|\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{\sigma^2}\right\} du &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{\sigma^2}\right\}du\\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\sigma^2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{u}{\sigma^2} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{\sigma^2}\right\}du\tag{1}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma,
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is a Rayleigh distribution.